# How to use ControllerAs feature of angular in gridOptions

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to use the ControllerAs in Template but result is blank.
the construct of my controller is like:

```
app.controller("MyController",function(){
 this.result=getResult();
this.gridOptions={data:'result'};
});
```

I'm using this controller as:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
 <div ng-grid="myCtrl.gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Using this.gridOptions={data:'myCtrl.result'}; will limit the controller to one instance only, is there any way like inject or something I can use, which takes up the instance from creation part ie. <div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
app.controller("MyController",function(){

    this.result=getResult();
    this.gridOptions={data:'myCtrl.result'};

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler look up 'results' in the $scope

You must use the alias instead,

like this:

```
app.controller("MyController",function(){
 this.result=getResult();
this.gridOptions={data:'myCtrl.result'};
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/22qXbu?p=preview

Comment: thank you, using this.gridOptions={data:'myCtrl.result'}; will limit the controller to one instance only, is there any way like inject or something I can use, which takes up the instance from creation part ie. <div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl"> @rnrneverdies ,@glendaviesnz